# how to add html form in php?

Tags: php, html, forms, isset

how do you add a html form in php? I have to check a condition from isset i.e if session has been set only then should the form be displayed.
ECHO statement is not working because of ""

```
<pre>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<br />
&nbsp;First Name:    Last Name:<br/>
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder ="First Name"/>  
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder ="Last Name"/><br />

&nbsp;Email-id:<br />
<input type="text" name="email-id" placeholder ="Your Email-id"/><br />

&nbsp;Password:<br />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder ="Your Password"/>
<br />
&nbsp;Re-enter Password:<br />
<input type="password" name="password1" placeholder ="Re-enter Password"/>
<br /></form><pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php if( isset( $_SESSION['someValue'] ) ): ?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <p>Whatevs...</p>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: are u sure? will this work

Comment: most definitely, check out http://nl3.php.net/html

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "I want to echo \"quotes\""; // prints: I want to echo "quotes"
echo 'I want to echo "quotes"'; // prints: I want to echo "quotes"
```

choose one, it both works. Or alternately:

```
<?php if($something == $the_same_as_this): ?>
   I want to print whatever I want, including "quotes"
<?php endif; ?>
```

Will output the string (as long as the expression evaluates true)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php if(your_condition_here): ?>
<form> your form here </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That way you don't have to use echo or print and make it complicated.